# Google App Engine - Spring Security Issue (java.security.AccessControlException)

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-security

I'm currently getting the AccessControlException below when I deploy to app engine (I don't see it when I run in my local environment). I'm using GAE 1.3.1, Spring 3.0.1, and Spring Security 3.0.2. Any ideas how to get around this issue? It appears to be an issue with Spring Security trying to get the system class loader, but I'm not sure how to work around this.

```
Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader):
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:567)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:45)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.findEditorByConvention(BeanUtils.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.findDefaultEditor(TypeConverterDelegate.java:360)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:213)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:888)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:530)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:191)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:168)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:235)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:5485)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:5483)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:24)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:363)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$2.run(Server.java:837)
    at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanRunnable.run(LocalTraceSpanRunnable.java:56)
    at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanBuilder.internalContinueSpan(LocalTraceSpanBuilder.java:536)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.startRpc(Server.java:792)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.processRequest(Server.java:367)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.ServerConnection.messageReceived(ServerConnection.java:448)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.parseMessages(RpcConnection.java:319)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.dataReceived(RpcConnection.java:290)
    at com.google.net.async.Connection.handleReadEvent(Connection.java:474)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.processNetworkEvents(EventDispatcher.java:774)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.internalLoop(EventDispatcher.java:205)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.loop(EventDispatcher.java:101)
    at com.google.net.rpc.RpcService.runUntilServerShutdown(RpcService.java:251)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RpcRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:394)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This may help: http://www.answercow.com/2010/02/spring-forms-on-google-app-engine.html

Comment: Same configuration and same problem here.  It works with Spring Security 3.0.0 M3, but I'd like to use the latest available version.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into 3.0.0 M3.

Comment: I've opened a bug against Spring Security. Please vote for it if you are facing this issue. http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SEC-1434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest versions I've been able to get to work together are Spring 3.0.1 and Spring Security 3.0.1. Using Spring Security 3.0.2 gives the exception described in the question. I've opened a bug against Spring Security [here](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SEC-1434). Please vote for it if you are facing this issue.

**Update**: Based on the feedback from Luke Taylor in the referenced bug this will be fixed in the 3.0.3 release and the 3.1 branch.

Comment: It also works the other side (keeping Spring 3.0.1 and switching back to Spring Security 3.0.0).  It would be great to know the cause...

Comment: Interesting, I will try that. I'm planning to open a ticket on Spring's bug tracker, but I'm not sure if it should go under the regular Spring or Spring Security projects.

Comment: It looks like Spring 3.0.1 and Spring Security 3.0.1 work as well.

Comment: This is fixed in the 3.0.3 Snapshot build.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem.  This doesn't have to do with Spring Security.  The cause of this is using Spring form tags on the app engine.  See http://www.answercow.com/2010/02/spring-forms-on-google-app-engine.html for more info and how to fix it.  I followed those directions and now everything works fine.

Comment: I'm not using the Spring forms tags on any of my JSP's though.

Comment: Ahh, didn't look deep enough into your stack trace to notice the difference.  Still though, the root cause is the call to `BeanUtils.findEditorByConvention`.  If you go into the Spring Source code and comment that method out and just return null from it, everything should be fine.  Read the link I provided for the reasoning why this works.

Comment: We should probably open a ticket with Spring regarding this if there isn't one already. It shouldn't be necessary to modify the source. Have you looked to see if there is a ticket open with Spring regarding this issue?

Comment: I haven't looked, but I agree, Spring should probably just catch the security exception in the method and just return null if there was an exception.

Comment: +1 In fact this work in Spring Security 3.0.0 M3 (latest version I've succesfully tried)

Comment: I logged a JIRA bug for the issue with the Spring form tags as well: http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-7042